# Setting the action text in JSP page in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I have in my properties file:

```
viewType.periodText=Period Report
viewType.periodValue=periodreport
```

and in JSP I am doing this:

```
<s:radio theme="simple" name="webAcModel.reportView" 
list="#{'%{getText('viewType.periodValue')}':
      '%{getText('viewType.periodText')}'}"></s:radio>
```

but it is giving me an error. But if I do this:

```
<s:radio theme="simple" name="webAcModel.reportView" 
list="#{'periodreport':'Period Report'}"></s:radio>
```

it works fine.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many symbols. There is no need for `%{}` inside `#{}` and since `getText` returns string `''` are not needed too.

```xml
<s:radio theme="simple" name="webAcModel.reportView"
          list="#{getText('viewType.periodValue'):
                  getText('viewType.periodText')}" />
```

BTW using `getText` for the submitted value from radio button isn't the best approach IMO.

Comment: thanks, i didnt mentioned in the question that there is also a grid that will be shown/hide on basis of these and also queries will be runned according to the selected so to make it consistent i used this approach.

Comment: @Haider: To make it consistent you should use some fixed key and not a property from the resources bundle. Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you.

Comment: e.g if i declare these keys in class e.g class Constant { public String peridvalue = "periodreport"  } then how i i use it ?

Comment: @Haider: Declare it like `static final` and use it.

Comment: in my class i have public static final String periodreport = "periodreport"; now when i use this <s:if test='%{webModel.reportView.equalsIgnoreCase(WebReportConstants.periodreport )}'> the condition is not true??

Comment: {@com.packagename.models.UsernameModel$UsernameTypes@ALIAS is there a short way to write this eacuse i am using it many times

Comment: @Haider **One** of the solutions is to set some variable in your JSP that will hold the required value (like this: `<s:set var="alias" value="@com.packagename.models.UsernameModel$UsernameTypes@ALIAS" />`) and reference it then as needed (e.g. `Alias value: <s:property value="#alias" />`)